# ImageView does not maintain constant height during orientation change

Tags: android, android-imageview

I have an XML layout which has an `ImageView` named `cust_img`, I might place an image of any dimension inside the `ImageView` but the height and the width must not change when the orientation changes. Currently this is not happening, could anyone suggest how could I achieve this?

I tried to apply the following `ScaleType` values

- CENTER
- CENTER_CROP
- CENTER_INSIDE
- FIT_CENTER
- FIT_END
- FIT_START
- FIT_XY
- MATRIX

None of them worked.

Here is my layout XML:

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="1"
            android:background="@color/white">

                <ScrollView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.94"
                    android:fillViewport="true">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:weightSum="1">

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:id="@+id/imglayout"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="0dp"
                            android:layout_weight="0.3"
                            android:gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:orientation="vertical">

                            <ImageView
                                android:id="@+id/cust_img"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                                android:maxHeight="150dp"
                                android:maxWidth="160dp" />
                        </LinearLayout>

                        <FrameLayout
                            android:id="@+id/frag_layout"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="0dp"
                            android:layout_weight="0.7"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
                        </FrameLayout>
                    </LinearLayout>
                </ScrollView>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.06">
                <include layout="@layout/footer_layout"/>
            </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Instead of keeping width match parent use both, height and width wrap content

Comment: @Praneeth Doesn't work\

Answer (score 1):

Instead of keeping width match parent use both, height and width wrap content.

Use image scale_type : `CENTER_CROP`.

```
    <ImageView
         android:id="@+id/cust_img"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
         android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
         android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
         android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
         android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>
```

Comment: @BatCat exactly what is happening when you change your orentation?

Comment: The height is decreased

Comment: Did you remove the max width and max height attributes?

Comment: Removed `android:layout_weight="0.3"` of `imgLayout` and it worked.

Comment: @BatCat yes, using weights will be good! if you think my answer helps you, feel free to upvote :P

Answer (score 0):

You have to put fix height to `ImageView`, otherwise give `wrap_content` to `ImageView` width.

Answer (score 0):

Change your imageview code with this

```
                          <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/cust_img"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                            android:maxHeight="150dp"
                            android:maxWidth="160dp" />
```